# How do I use proxy in Flex 4's HTML control?

Tags: apache-flex, proxy, flex4, air, htmlcontrols

I want to use a proxy on the HTML Control found in Adobe AIR. How do I go about doing this? I have tried looking at the AS3 docs on Adobe but honestly, it didn't explain the usage clearly to me and looking at Adobe's example, I can't seem to make out anything off of it. If anyone would be kind enough to provide me with a simple example, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Air browser uses the OS' browser. Hence, if you want to set the proxy settings on an Air application, you must set the system's proxy settings.

Comment: I think it doesn't use the OS's browser which is IE for me. I think the HTML control for Air uses Webkit?

Comment: I beg to differ: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/244550?tstart=-1 and http://www.flex-tutorial.fr/2009/01/05/flex-air-configurer-le-proxy-internet-dans-une-application-adobe-air-resolu/  This last one is french, but says that he configured his proxy by configuring IE's proxy.